# How do I invoke a class method using pcall in lua?

Tags: lua

How do I invoke a class method using `pcall` in Lua?

I tried `pcall(instance:method, arg)` but it doesn't work.
I also tried `pcall(instance.method, instance, arg)` but that doesn't work either.

I googled for a solution but I couldn't get one.

An example:

```
local ValueOwnerMap = {}

ValueOwnerMap.__index = ValueOwnerMap

function ValueOwnerMap:create(key_prefix)
    local instance = {}
    setmetatable(instance, ValueOwnerMap)
    instance.key = key_prefix .. ':value-owner-map'
    return instance
end

function ValueOwnerMap:get(value)
    return redis.call('HGET', self.key, value)
end

function ValueOwnerMap:put(value, owner_id)
    return redis.call('HSETNX', self.key, value, owner_id)
end

function ValueOwnerMap:del(value)
    return redis.call('HDEL', self.key, value)
end

local value_owner_map = ValueOwnerMap:create('owner:key')
local success, data = pcall(value_owner_map:put, 'a_value', 'a_owner_id')
```

Comment: Show some [MCVE] in your question. Do you want pure lua, or C code?

Comment: pure lua, please

Comment: Lua is not an object-oriented language.  There are several possibilities to emulate object orientation but you have to let us know which one you're using.  To this end please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: I've added the example

Comment: `pcall(instance.method, instance, arg) but that doesn't work either` it works for me

Answer (score 8):

`instance:method(arg)` is sugar for `instance.method(instance,arg)`. So try

```
pcall(value_owner_map.put, value_owner_map, 'a_value', 'a_owner_id')
```

Comment: Why doesn't lua pcall considers this `instance:method`a method?

Comment: @wsha, perhaps ask a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

The following line replaces the last line of the block in the question. It works.

```
local success, data = pcall(function () value_owner_map:put('a_value', 'a_owner_id') end)
```

Thank you all for sharing

Answer (score -1):

> pcall (f, arg1, ···)

Calls function f with the given arguments in protected mode. This means that any error inside f is not propagated; instead, pcall catches the error and returns a status code. [lua ref](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html)

But Calls for functions in protected mode have some limitations especially when you are using ':' operator 'so-called synthetic sugar' of lua. 
one way to WAR this limitation is to put inside a function

```
pcall(function () value_owner_map:put('a_value', 'a_owner_id') end)
```

This approach also catches the errors as usual:

```
local ok, msg = pcall(function () error('Phony Error') end)

if ok then 
    print("No error")
else 
    print("Got error".. tostring(msg))
end
-- Result:
-- Got error test.lua:53: Phony Error
```

Comment: The second block of code definitely does not work. Since arguments are existed before functions, a `pcall` used in that way will not catch errors. Besides,`:put` does not return a function. The first argument to `pcall` must be a function.

Comment: 1. "The second block of code definitely does not work Since arguments have existed before functions" Have you tried it yourself? 2. pcall used in that way will not catch errors. Yes, it will, please test with forced error. 3.  Yes, the first argument is a function

Comment: > print("result", pcall(error("foo"))) --> stdin:1: foo  (no `result` visible)

Comment: > print("result", pcall(function() error("foo") end)) --> result false stdin:1: foo

Comment: Please see my answer, i added an example

Comment: You have fundamentally changed the code in your answer. What you have written now is exactly what the other answers have said to do: A bare function call as an argument to `pcall` does not do what you want you. It needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function or be broken into a function and its arguments afterwards.

Comment: the removed code was said to be clumsy behavior. Nevertheless on the same page